# Why Collection<String>s= new TreeSet<>(), TreeSet<String>s= new TreeSet<>() and Set<String>s = new TreeSet<>() produces same result?

Tags: java, collections

I don't understand why all three are same. Collection is an interface and TreeSet and Set are Classes.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] text = {"i", "came", "i", "saw", "i", "left"};

        Set<String> s = new TreeSet<>();    // output = 4 distinct words: [came, i, left, saw]
        // Collection<String>s = new TreeSet<>(); // output = 4 distinct words: [came, i, left, saw]
        // TreeSet<String>s = new TreeSet<>(); // output = 4 distinct words: [came, i, left, saw]
        for(String a: text)
            s.add(a);

            System.out.println(s.size()+" distinct words: "+s);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is same because all three are using the same implementation class which is `TreeSet`. Since `Set` and `Collection` are the parent interfaces of the `TreeSet` class you can point to a `TreeSet` implementation using the their reference. This is how *polymorphism* works in OOP.

But although the reference is of `Set` or `Collection` the implementation is an instance of the class `TreeSet` which does not allow duplicates and sorts the elements as per their definition of the `Comparable` interface (natural ordering). So in all three you are seeing that the duplicates are eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the same *implementation* in all three cases and assigning to its supertypes. Please look at [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).